# Smarty foreach how to start at array 1 not 0

Tags: foreach, smarty

i have like a 2 foreach loops, first one with a image. So thats only the first item. But in me second foreach i wanted to start showing the result at array 1. Not 0 then i have like 2 times the second post.

First foreach

```
{foreach $cm->find('title,url,auteur,datum,reacties,topics,afbeelding,tekst', 'Blog') as $item} 
    {if $item@first}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Second for each

```
{foreach $cm->find('title,url,auteur,datum,reacties,topics,tekst', 'Blog') as $item}
{/foeach}
```

What do i need to add in me second foreach to start showing my results started by array 1.

Sorry if this a noob question, im not really good at smarty.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can skip the first item in the second foreach with {continue}:

```
{foreach $cm->find('title,url,auteur,datum,reacties,topics,afbeelding,tekst', 'Blog') as $item} 
    {if $item@first}
      {continue}
    {/if}
    ... code for the other items here ...
{/foreach}
```